# unable to deploy after upgrading to 1.7.4

Tags: google-app-engine

I upgraded today to GAE 1.7.4 and on trying to deploy I see following error:

```
Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\VSKUMA~1.ST-\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg4811921061542689032.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE.
```

I already have JDK pointing in the build path and this all was working fine till GAE 1.7.3

I cannot uninstall the existing GREs for some reasons.

Comment: Maybe you can uninstall the JRE on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i uninstalled jre manually and this only helped me to get through this

Answer (score 25):

For me at least, forcing Eclipse to use a different vm itself worked. Add, for example:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\<jdk1.6.0_38>\bin\javaw.exe
```

to the first two lines* of the eclipse.ini file and restart Eclipse.

**Thanks to Andre*

Comment: doesnt work. returns with exit code =1 and even changing to the option to jvm.dll still fails

Comment: Make sure that `-vm` is the first line in your `eclipse.ini` and that the path to the `javaw.exe` goes into the 2nd line. That should do the trick.

Comment: I had the same problem after a fresh install on Windows 8. This solution worked

Comment: After above change - eclipse failed to start with error - 'java was started but returned exit code=1'

Answer (score -1):

Yes @Vik, i had this problem when updating to GAE 1.7.3 and the solution to the problem is to reinstall the JRE... but! if you are working with Eclipse, and this doesn´t work either, try reintalling the whole IDE. (i had to do so, and it worked for me ¬¬ )