# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. What could be the reason for it?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I am really having trouble starting with eclipse. I want to configure eclipse so that it uses the version `7` for both the *jdk* and *jre*. How can I do this.

Right now,when I try to deploy my application to `google app engine`, I get this message :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use
a JDK, not a JRE.
```

This is my configuration for the *installed jre* section :

[image]

What could be the reason for the problem ? Please give an insight into the problem.

Comment: Run Configurations... -> JRE tab

Comment: Can you give us the complete path of the JDK Location?

Comment: A JDK contains the JRE...

Comment: @PabloLozano `home/non-admin/jdk1.7.0_02/`

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938995/google-app-engine-jsp-cant-deploy-java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-get-the-s?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get the System Java Compiler. Please use a JDK, not a JRE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985363/cannot-get-the-system-java-compiler-please-use-a-jdk-not-a-jre)

Answer (score -1):

The reason is just what the error message says: The Google App Engine apparently will not run your code with a JDK, but only a JRE.

Your eclipse JRE/JDK settings do not matter here. They can't cause your deployment target to suddenly have a JDK installed. But since you use JDK features (like the compiler), your app will not run where only a JRE is installed.

For a remedy, you can bundle the eclipse compiler `ecj.jar` (you'll find it somewhere in the internet or even via maven) with your application, and rewrite the part that compiles stuff accordingly.

Comment: It quite the opposite: a JDK is needed.

Comment: @PabloLozano  How is thta the opposite?

Comment: You have written that GAE does not run in a JDK, but the error message says "Please use a JDK"

Comment: @PabloLozano You must be confused. The message appears precisely **because** he **needs** an JDK, but GAE has none. That is what I said!

Comment: @PabloLozano Yes, this is the reason for the error. It does not run a JDK, but he needs it. Hard to understand, is it?

Comment: Ok, I got it: what you really mean is *"The GAE apparently is not running on a JDK, but only on a JRE"*. If you use present simple the meaning changes a lot. PS: the downvote is not mine :(

Comment: @Ingo can you tell me the way, I can solve this problem

Comment: @Ingo I didn't know,deploying to gae via **eclipse** was such a complicated task

Comment: @PabloLozano While I do not believe that "apparently does not run a JDK" means "it runs a JDK" I have edited a bit.

Comment: @SuhailGupta You need to understand that it has nothing to do with eclipse (how you deploy it), but *what* you deploy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985363/cannot-get-the-system-java-compiler-please-use-a-jdk-not-a-jre It was not too complex ! Just had to add one line in the `eclipse.ini` file